# Can I use ping to see real time drop rates?

Tags: command-line, ping

I'm pinging a server which is dropping packets. At the end of my ping I see something like:

```
100 packets transmitted, 85 received, 15% packet loss, time 100030ms
```

What I'd like to do is run my ping continuously but be able to tell when packets are being dropped.

My first thought is to watch the icmp_seq number and look for missing numbers. I'd like to automate this process via a pipe.  Something along the lines of:

```
ping server.wherever.com | cut --someoptionshere | some other program
```

that would display output only when packets were dropped (as opposed to when the were received as ping does).

Is there any such sequence of pipes I could do to create this?

Comment: You really want to look into "mtr"

Answer (score 4):

You may checkout:

`ping -f <ip>`

This will do a floodping display a single dot for every sent REQUEST and remove a single dot for every REPLY.

If there is **no package loss** you **wont see anything** because the count of REQUEST eq REPLY.

If **there is package loss** you **see more and more** `.`

http://linux.die.net/man/8/ping